# Firebase push notification token returning empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am struggling to get Firbase Push notifications working:

I have the following services in my Android manifest file:

```
    <service android:name=".notifications.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".notifications.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

The code for MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

        private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            preferences.edit().putString(Constants.FIREBASE_TOKEN, refreshedToken).apply();
    }
}
```

My StartActivity consists of the following

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static boolean isAppRunning;

private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private final String TAG="token";
private String token;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    startService(new Intent(this,MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class));
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.FIREBASE_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
    token=mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.FIREBASE_TOKEN,"");
    Log.d(TAG, "token:" + token);

}

}
```

You will see that that I manually start the service (not sure if I have to), but the issue is the token is always empty.

Comment: what do you get in `Log.d` when you run app first time.( MyFirebaseInstanceIDService) ?

Comment: it returns "token: "

Comment: i am talking about `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` class .

Comment: it does not return anything I dont even pick up Refreshed token: . I get the following errors not sure if it is related :08-12 15:05:10.175 22194-22194/? D/token: token:
08-12 15:05:14.509 22495-22495/? I/AASAservice-TokenRule: parseToken()
08-12 15:05:14.519 22495-22495/? W/System.err:     at com.samsung.aasaservice.AASATokenRule.parseToken(AASATokenRule.java:86)
08-12 15:05:14.519 22495-22495/? E/AASAservice-TokenRule: parseToken() : TokenFile is null

Comment: Have a look at official  FCM sample project - and compare to it :) https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

Comment: thanks so much will do

Comment: Have you added google-services.json correctly or not ?